# R: Where to place winprogressbar code in an existing loop?

Tags: r, loops

I would like to add a progress bar to my script in R, but I'm not sure where to put this in my loop. The code for the winProgressbar is below from the internet. Where should I place this code in my loop?

Thanks!

pb <- winProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0,
                      max = total, width = 300)

```
for(i in 1:total){
 Sys.sleep(0.1)
 setWinProgressBar(pb, i, title=paste( round(i/total*100, 0),
                                       "% done"))
 }
 close(pb)
```

Comment: did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To track the progress of an entire script or program, you just need to place the initializing function (`winProgressBar`) at the beginning of the code and do updates via `setWinProgressBar` at key points within the flow of your program. For example, if the first task your code performs usually takes about 10% of the total time required, set the value to 10% after that task completes.

Your code may look something like the following:

```
your_function <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  #add random stuff here like loading packages

#create your progress bar
pb <- winProgressBar(title = "progress bar", min = 0, max = 100, width = 300)

#insert part 1 of your code, let's say it takes 10% of your total processing time

setWinProgressBar(pb, 10, label = paste(round(10/total*100, 0),"% done"))

#insert part 2 of your code, let's say it takes 25% of your total processing time

setWinProgressBar(pb, 35, label = paste(round(35/total*100, 0),"% done"))

etc...

close(pb)

}
```

You can also place it on the outside of your function similar to the example you provided.